# How to make enum with string constants

Tags: scala

I have scopt parser which accepts color parameter ("green", "red", "blue"). I want to put String constants in enum, could u help me write it and locate it in best place in project (maybe package.scala)?

```
  def getColor(config: Config) =
    config.color match {
      case "green"    => print("green")
      case "red"      => print("red")
      case "blue"     => print("blue")
    }
```

Comment: What have you tried? what are the requirements of your enum?

Answer (score 2):

This is actually described in [Scopt documentation](https://github.com/scopt/scopt#options). As long as your enum is a separate type you can create `scopt.Read` for it.

```
// enumeration
object Color extends Enumeration {
  type Color = Value
  val Red, Green, Blue = Value
}
// has to be imported manually as we cannot put it into `Value` companion
implicit val colorRead: scopt.Read[Color.Value] =
  scopt.Read.reads(Color withName _)
```

```
// enumeratum
sealed trait Color EnumEntry
object Color extends Enum[Color] {
  case object Red extends Color
  case object Green extends Color
  case object Blue extends Color
  val values = findValues

  implicit val colorRead: scopt.Read[Color] =
    scopt.Read.reads(Color withName _)
}
```

```
// normal sealed trait
sealed trait Color EnumEntry
object Color extends Enum[Color] {
  case object Red extends Color
  case object Green extends Color
  case object Blue extends Color

  implicit val colorRead: scopt.Read[Color] =
    scopt.Read.reads {
      case "green" => Color.Green
      case "red"   => Color.Red
      case "blue"  => Color.Blue
    }
}
```

If you made `color` field of `Config` of type `Color`, implicit `Read[Color]` will make it possible to parse `opt[Color]` option in config.